# Error while observing MutableLiveData

Tags: java, android, mvvm, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm working on a MVVM app. I've been able to use AndroidViewModel, Activity and MutableLiveData together, but I don't know why am I having problem with this specific method.

For example, I've an AndroidViewModel Called "IssuesViewModel". It has a `private MutableLiveData<Boolean> mutable;` and this two methods:

```
// Retrofit 2 call
public void reportIssue(Data data){
    mutable = new MutableLiveData();
    retrofit.reportIssue(Data data, new RestCallback<Void>(){
        @Override
        public void success(Void success){
            mutable.setValue(true);
        }
        @Override
        public void failure(){
            mutable.setValue(false);
        }
    );
}

// Getting mutableLiveData
public MutableLiveData<Boolean> getMutable(){
    return mutable;
}
```

Now, in my "IssuesActivity", that is extending `AppCompatActivity` and implementing `LifecycleRegistryOwner`, I have this methods:

```
//... Activity callbacks and other methods ...
private IssuesViewModel viewModel;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // Toolbar code and other stuff...
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(IssuesViewModel.class);
    // More code ...
}

@Override
public LifecycleRegistry getLifecycle() {
    return new LifecycleRegistry(this);
}

// Triggered after button click
private void reportIssue(Data data){
    viewModel.reportIssue(data);
    viewModel.getMutable().observe(this, new Observer<Boolean>(){
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable Boolean response){
            if (response != null && response){
                //Success, update UI
            } else {
                //Error, update UI
            }
    }
}
```

I've been able to use mutableLiveData before (with custom Object instead of Boolean). I did the same for all my previous calls... I don't know why this is not working.

Thanks!

**Edit 1, Nov 21th:**

I think the problem is that my activity extends `AppCompatActivity` and implements `LifecycleRegistryOwner`. I have an Activity with similar code to the one above and everything works, but that Activity is extending `LifecycleActivity`. When I change this activity, extending `AppCompatActivity` and implementing`LifecycleRegistryOwner`, observer's onChange **never triggers**. I found this [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62160522#comment1) that is related with my problem, but I think it just works with Fragments...

Comment: is the problem that on changed is not called? also instead of getMutable(), you can return the mutable on reportIssue() instead of void

Comment: yes, for some reason, onChanged is never called... I tried returning mutable on `reportIssue()` but I didn't work

Comment: each time you call `reportIssue` the value of `mutable` is set to a new value but your activity client may use the old value - simply initialize `mutable = new MutableLiveData();` in one place inside your view model

Comment: I put it inside IssuesViewModel's constructor, but it didn't work either @pskink

Comment: The problem seems to occur because of the reason @pskink mention. I've made a sample app to demonstrate MVVM with commonly used libraries here https://github.com/dgngulcan/nytclient-android you can check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved after updating `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions` to stable version 1.0.0. Now, everything works as expected.